# Latex math expression in RMarkdown table column name

Tags: r, latex, knitr, r-markdown

I want to display a table in my markdown document and set the column names to be Latex mathematical formulas such as $\dot(m)_1$.

I tried this:

```
knitr::kable(my.df[, c("Time", "MassFlowRate")],
             row.names = FALSE,
             col.names = c("Time", "$\dot{m}_1$"))
```

But it doesn't work.

I don't generate a PDF, but a Word document in the end. So directly coding a Latex table is not an option.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to escape `\` passed into R code so `\dots` should be `\\dots`:

````
```{r}
my.df <- data.frame(Time=rnorm(10), MassFlowRate = rnorm(10))
knitr::kable(my.df[, c("Time", "MassFlowRate")],
             row.names = FALSE,
             col.names = c("Time", "$\\dot{m}_1$"))
```
````

Comment: Any ideas why I can't get this to work in `add_header_above`?  I am writing to a PDF and my code is something like `add_header_above(c('5% $\\leq$'=2`

Comment: this is an old answer, I have no idea... You should ask a new question showing what's wrong in your output (I'm guessing the fact that `\\` is rendered as `\textbacklash{}`)

Answer (score 8):

To get the current answer to work, you need to add `, escape = FALSE` in `kable()`.

Also, I prefer using a `tibble` to a `data.frame`. That way I can specify the LaTeX code in the column names directly. No need to use `col.names`.

````
```{r}
library(tibble)
my_df <- tibble(Time=rnorm(10), `$\\dot{m}_1$` = rnorm(10))
knitr::kable(my_df, escape = FALSE)
```
````

Comment: Thanks much for this - helped me solve my problem. This said, no need to use `tibble`, which some posts warn against. base R `data.frame` works just as well - only need to specify `check.names = FALSE` so that no forced conversion takes place